# JetBrains DataGrip - Azure SQL - connect with Active Directory - Password

Tags: azure-active-directory, datagrip, ssms-2016

Is it possible to connect to Azure SQL database the same way as I would with Microsoft SQL Management Studio - the "**Active Directory - Password**" option.

[image]

[I followed the instructions from here (JetBrains documentation)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connecting-to-a-database.html#ms_azure) but when I select "**Use Windows Domain authentication**" (as I should for Azure Active Directory) it doesn't let me to enter the credentials as SSMS does.

Everything works fine with SSMS but with DataGrip I have no luck. Is this option just not supported in there?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was posted by https://codejuicer.com/, copied from following blog: https://codejuicer.com/2018/08/29/datagrip-and-azure-sql-server-active-directory-howto/

> **Step 1:** Get A Few Required JARs. The main library you’ll be working
>   with is ADAL4J
>   (https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/wiki/ADAL4J-Basics).
>   The simplest way to do this step, in my opinion, is to use a barebones
>   Maven pom.xml. That way you don’t have to compile from source and find
>   all the dependencies manually. Horray!
>
> If you don’t have Maven (https://maven.apache.org/) installed you’ll
>   need it. If you prefer Gradle, I’m sure the same can be accomplished
>   with that.
>
> This is what my pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
          <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.2</version>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <directory>lib</directory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>
            ${project.build.directory}
          </outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

> Now run this command wherever your pom.xml is at:

```
mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies
```

> It will create a “lib” directory containing all the jars you need.
>
> **Step 2:** Add the JARs to the Azure (Microsoft) Driver
>   1. In the Data Sources and Drivers window (File menu), select the Azure (Microsoft) driver. In the Driver files pane, click the + button
>   and select “Custom JARs...“
>   [image]
>   2. Navigate to the JARs fetched in Step 1. Select all of them.
>   [image] Your screen should look
>   something like this (aside from the fancy blurs to hide my super
>   secret info).
>   [image]
>   **Step 3:** Altering the Advanced Connection Options There is only one
>   thing you need to change for Active Directory authentication. The
>   authentication method. It’s really easy.
>
> At this point, I’m assuming you have an existing connection. If not,
>   create one and select the Azure (Microsoft) driver.
>
> Navigate to the Advanced tab. I like to sort the options by Name.
>   However you do it, find the setting named “authentication.”
>
> Click in the Value column and select ActiveDirectoryPassword (if
>   you’re on Windows™ and use integrated AD… select
>   ActiveDirectoryIntegrated).
>   [image]
>   I imagine I don’t have to tell you to “click OK or Apply.”
>
> **Success** (I hope)! At this point you should be able to log in to your
>   database instance. Of course, that assumes your credentials and
>   hostname are correct. I hope this helps!

Comment: Shouldn't it be enough to add only adal4j jar?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible.

1. Use JTDS driver, not Microsoft one.
2. Go to the Advanced tab of data source properties, set USENTLMV2 to true and specify the domain name in the DOMAIN field.
   [image]
3. Then enter your Active Directory credentials in user/password fields and click Test Connection.

Comment: All I get is: Connection to SQL Server (jTds) - xxx@xxx.database.windows.net failed.
[S1000][40607] Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Comment: Ah, sorry, You need to make some manipulations then: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000014000-Can-t-sign-into-Azure-DB-with-Datagrip-but-can-with-SMSS

Comment: Thank you for the link, I wish it was clear what to do with the issue but the issue itself seems to be unresolved and very unclear.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted. It worked exactly for me.