# Connect to Azure database with DataGrip - Active Directory

Tags: sql-server, azure, datagrip

I am trying to connect to Azure database via DataGrip using Active Directory connection (Note: not Active directory - password) 
I followed accepted answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097779/jetbrains-datagrip-azure-sql-connect-with-active-directory-password)
I set `integratedSecurity=false` and `authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated`.
When trying to connect to `Test Connection` I get error message 
`Connection to Azure SQL Database failed. Cannot set "Authetication" with "IntegratedSecurity" set to "true"`.
Is it some kind of bug that can be repaired, if so how could I solve this issue?

Edit:
More information:
On Azure Portal I can see that this is `SQL database`.
Server name ends with `database.windows.net`.

When I try to connect via Connection String (in Data Grip `Add data from URL`) generated by Azure I am not able to connect also.

Answer (score 1):

The DataGrip support us using  Azure Active Directory Authentication. Please see: [Microsoft Azure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/2018.2/connecting-to-a-database.html#ms_azure) .

You can get the connect string (URL) with Active Directory integrated authentication from Portal:
[image]

Replace the URL with the Connect string(Active Directory integrated authentication):

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does not help. Still the same problem.
```Cannot set "Authentication" with "IntegratedSecurity" set to "true".```

Comment: If you don't set the "IntegratedSecurity=true", can this works?

Comment: I even set it to false. The error still persists. I guess it's DataGrip bug, but not sure about it. I am behind proxy, it might also be an issue, but I specified it in the proxy settings.

Comment: yeah, we can't find more articles talked about Active Directory integrated authentication.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of confusion around terminology here.

In short, the connection string attribute `Integrated Security=true` indicates you want to use "windows authentication". This type of authentication *might* be supported by any Azure SQL (anything whose hostname ends in `database.windows.net`). Azure SQL only supports Azure Active Directory authentication, butit *might* be possible to implement single sign on between a windows domain account and Azure Active Directory.

Comment: I can connect via "Active Directory - Integrated" option in SSMS. Is it something different? More over, in thread I linked someone has successfully connect to Azure via DataGrip, so I guess you cannot be fully right that it cannot be done with Active Directory.

Comment: There’s confusion over terminology. You definitely cannot connect to any Azure SQL using “Windows Authentication”. In this case “Active Directory” is being used interchangeably with “Azure Active Directory”. It makes it confusing to explain.

Comment: I have substantially reworded my answer. It's not really an answer anymore. Can you edit your original question and clarify what kind of SQL Server you are connecting to. Does the server name end in `database.windows.net`?

Comment: Yes, server name ends with ```database.windows.net```.

Comment: I've since learnt that it _is_ possible to log into Azure AD from a windows account if you have a "federated" setup, but I don't know much about it. I think I'll delete this answer because its incorrect and misleading

Comment: What do you mean by "federated"?

Comment: I can't find a simple explanation. Here's one thing to read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication#trust-architecture here's another https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso neither are simple to understand. If you want your domain account to log into Azure AD you'll need your "windows administator" to set it up first